# SwiftUI Leading & Trailing Alignment

Tags: swiftui, alignment

I'm trying to create a simple chat bubble, with the message left (leading) aligned and the timestamp right aligned.

It should have a minimum width of 100 and dynamically grow based on the size of the message (with extra padding to the right/end/trailing to push it to the left/start).

Basically, I'm trying to replicate this:

[image]

```
struct ReceivedMessageRow: View {
    var text:String
    var messageTime: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(text)
                Text(messageTime)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(8)
            .border(.red, width: 3)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            Spacer()
        }
        .border(.blue)
        .padding(.leading, 8)
        .padding(.trailing, 48)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

I have it mostly there, but cannot get the timestamp to right align.
[image]

If I wrap it in an HStack with a spacer, it grows the whole bubble, which I don't want

```
...
 VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(text)
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text(messageTime)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
               
            }
...
```

[image]

This should be simple but I've been scratching my head for hours - please someone put me out of my misery

Answer (score 2):

Using an `overlay` can get you the behavior you want (which will let you align to the right without affecting the parent size).

One important element is dealing with the size you need to add to the stack in order to make it "fit" that new element. I've chosen to include the `messageTimeView` *twice* to solve this -- once with an opacity of 0 to just make sure the `Stack` is tall enough to accommodate the element and once in the real overlay.

This strategy would allow you to change the font size of the timestamp and not worry that the layout would break.

```
struct ReceivedMessageRow: View {
    var text:String
    var messageTime: String
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var messageTimeView: some View {
        Text(messageTime)
            .font(.caption)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(text)
                messageTimeView
                    .opacity(0)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, alignment: .leading)
            .overlay(
                messageTimeView
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                           maxHeight: .infinity,
                           alignment: .bottomTrailing)
            )
            .padding(8)
            .border(.red, width: 3)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            Spacer()
        }
        .border(.blue)
        .padding(.leading, 8)
        .padding(.trailing, 48)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this causes the whole VStack to expand to full width. If the text is shorter than a whole line, I don't want the chat bubble to extend, it should only be as wide as the text (or minWidth, whichever is larger). This results in the same outcome as using a spacer.

Comment: My apologies -- please see the updated answer

Comment: @CharlieWalker Did you check my update? If it doesn't answer your question, can you clarify what is missing?